Помощь с рефакторингом
Писал тестовое для Java Backend вакансии у себя в компании.Вот текст документа с заданием:

User ManagProject Title: Library Management System   This project is
about creating a Library Management System, a software tool to help
library staff manage books, patrons (library users), and book
borrowing in an easy and efficient way.
Key Features: ement:
Create and manage librarian accounts.
Allow librarians to log in.
Book Management:
    Add new books with details like title, author, ISBN, and genre.
    Edit and update book info.
    Remove books from the library.
    Display a list of all library books.

Patron Management:
    Add new patrons with their names, contact info, and membership status.
    Edit and update patron details.
    Remove patrons from the library.
    Show a list of all library patrons.

Borrowing System:
    Enable library patrons to borrow books.
    Track due dates for borrowed books.
    Allow librarians to mark books as returned.
    Notify patrons if they have overdue books.

Search and Filtering:
    Create a search feature for books and patrons based on criteria like title, author, and name.
    Add options to sort and filter lists of books and patrons.

Reporting:
    Generate reports that display overdue books and transaction history.
    Provide statistics about the library's book collection and patron activity.   Technical Details:

User Interface:
    Design an easy-to-use web-based interface for librarians.
    Ensure it works well on different screen sizes.

Security:
    Set up user login and access control for librarians.
    Safeguard sensitive information, like passwords and patron data.

Database:
    Use a relational database (e.g., MySQL, PostgreSQL) to store book, patron, and transaction data.
    Create a suitable database structure and relationships.

Performance:
    Optimize how the system fetches data from the database.
    Ensure the system can handle multiple users at once.

Scalability:
    Design the system to grow smoothly as the library's needs expand.   Technology Stack:

Backend: Java (with Spring Boot)
Frontend: HTML, CSS, JavaScript
Database: Relational (e.g., MySQL, PostgreSQL)
Security: Spring Security
Database Access: Hibernate
User Interface Templating: Thymeleaf or similar   Project Deliverables:

The project's source code.
Documentation (README) explaining how to set up and run the application.
Brief documentation describing the project's structure and design choices.
Source code should be provided as a git repository.   Evaluation Criteria:   The project will be assessed based on:

Functionality: Does the system meet all functional requirements?
User Interface: Is the interface user-friendly and adaptable to different devices?
Code Quality: Is the code well-organized, readable, and maintainable?
Security: Is user authentication and data protection implemented correctly?
Database Design: Does the database structure fit the project's needs?
Documentation: Is there clear documentation for setting up and using the application?
Error Handling: Does the application handle errors gracefully?
Performance: How efficiently does the application perform its tasks?


После сдачи тестового сказали что видно что "писал самуочка"(это правда) и сказали исправить и потом попробовать еще,но к сожалению что конкретно с заданием не так не подсказали.У самого не получается найти что конкретно надо исправить.Буду рад если подскажете.Вот ссылка на проект на гитхабе

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос. начните с формулировки заголовка.

Ну они могли бы хотя бы ответить, что они в ответах на нижние вопросы вам проставили, чтобы было ясно, что не так )

Сразу дисклеймер: накидать замечаний можно много, но не факт, что точки зрения отвечающих и проверяющих совпадут. Поэтому желательно было бы узнать от первоисточника, что им не понравилось и что следует исправить. От себя я могу просто показать, где конкретно я вижу проблемы и что можно улучшить.

Оформление пояснительного файла к проекту в git идет через файл readme.md с разметкой markdown и пишется он не в три не особо ясные строки.

Оформление базы данных идет через файлы SQL сложенных в отдельном месте и прогоняемых отдельно на базе данных. У вас помимо того, что схема привязана к приложению, так часть еще вдобавок идет вставкой кодом. В исходниках под это сделано даже два дублирующих класса DataInitializer.java  и UserDataInitializer.java.

Схема базы данных должна отвечать требованиям, что-то сделано непонятно зачем и для чего, чего-то не хватает.


Есть в системе Роли (role) в отдельной таблице и есть Пользователи (user) в отдельной таблице. Кстати оба слова могут быть зарезервированными базой данных, поэтому обычно пишут roles/users и придерживаются одинакового наименования во множестве числе. Вот зачем существует текстовое поле user.role в этой схеме?
Или книги и их выдача, есть таблица loan, которая описывает выдачу. Зачем тогда в таблице книг существует books.patron_id? Почему transactions, а не loan_history? Сама таблица loan уже содержит все необходимые сведения, даже отдельно историю добавлять не нужно (можно для приличия добавить планируемую дату возврата, чтобы отслеживать фактические возвраты и просрочку).
Это если по существу, а не по существу можно еще накидывать. К примеру, у книги может быть несколько авторов и несколько жанров. Комментарии в схеме отсутствуют, хотя база позволяет их вести (COMMENT option). Статусы и другое проходят через магические константы, вот что такое transactions.transaction_type, если оно просто текстовое без привязки к чему-то.
Еще patreon могут рассматриваться как те же самые пользователи. Если когда-нибудь сервис захочет дать пользователям самим искать книги на терминале, им желательно дать доступ с отдельными правами и входом. Тогда таблица patreon отпадет сама собой как излишняя. Распределение только по правам и при этом сами работники могут быть такими же пользователями.
В этих случаях схема может выглядеть следующим образом.


Работа с UX/UI

Представьте себя работником этой программы и подумайте, что могло бы быть удобным и что нет. К примеру, если я захожу в раздел с книгами, я хочу удобным образом с ними работать.
Первое же, что я вижу, что большая часть книг мне не доступна на просмотр и почему-то я должен отдельно нажимать на кнопку borrowed books, иначе в списке я их просто не найду. Можно же тоже самое сделать фильтром, а не заставлять человека ходит по разным формам.
Если в библиотеке будет несколько тысяч книг, то листать вниз до кнопок я буду до вечера :) Почему они не сверху и пробовали ли вы добавить больше пяти книг в базу? Больше пяти пользователей? Если мне нужен перекрестный поиск, то он не реализован. Для всего это есть и Pageable и CriteriaBuilder. Есть куда стремится.
Отсутствует статистическая информация, к примеру, сколько книг за месяц было взято, вернули, вернули с задержкой? Ну и есть пункт adaptable to different devices, внимательно проверяйте как себя ведет приложение на разных экранах.
В общем думайте об удобстве.

Ну и наконец сам код.

К структуре папок и файлов особо нечего отметить неправильно. Сам код тоже оформлен с нормальной разбивкой на контроллеры/сервисы/репозитории. А дальше сложно сказать, что хотят увидеть проверяющие, поскольку практики и методы использования есть различные. Вот тут вам надо уточнять обязательно у проверявших.
Можно разве что порассуждать на тему DTO нормальных вместо Entity, которые должны быть отделены друг от друга. А так же проверки, которые можно туда же запихнуть (аннотации @Max, @Min, @NotNull, etc).
Необязательность разных адресов для Get/Post, они прекрасно будут работать на одном @GetMapping("/book/create") + @PostMapping("/book/create").

Большое спасибо!

@DavitKobalia, если в требованиях была реализация именно REST API, могло сильно не понравиться наличие "ненужных" глаголов create/update в ендпойнтах, т.е. хватило бы GET /books, GET /books/{id}, POST /books и т.п.
